# implementing Router to change pages in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

I am making a react.js shopping list app I have it so that you input the values and can print them out into a table. This is my first time using react and I want to have my table on a separate page I am aware of ROUTER method but am having trouble implementing it.

Here is my code
note: I have not added any thing to navigate between pages yet but i want the print button to navigate to from App.js to Details.js

```
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import "./App.css";
import Counters from "./components/counters";
import Details from "./Details";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      //example of objects in array
      /*{ id: 1, value: 2, text: "hi" },*/
    ],
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("app- constructor");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("app- mouneted");
  }

  handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleDecrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value--;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.map((c) => {
      c.value = 0;
      return c;
    });
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleName = () => {
    var name = prompt("name");
    return name;
  };

  handleCreate = () => {
    const create = this.state.counters.length + 1;
    const counter = this.state.counters.push({
      id: create,
      value: 0,
      text: this.handleName(),
    });
    this.setState({ counter });
  };

  handleDelete = (counterId) => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter((c) => c.id !== counterId);
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleInfo = () => {
    let x;
    //loops through all tems and adds the to the list
    for (x = 0; x <= this.state.counters.length; x++) {
      //breaks loop if x is == to counters array
      if (this.state.counters.length == x) {
        break;
      }
      const info = this.state.counters[x]["text"];
      const quantity = this.state.counters[x]["value"];
      console.log(info, quantity);

      //creates rows based on input
      var table = document.getElementById("myList");
      var row = table.insertRow(1);
      var itemCell = row.insertCell(0);
      var quantityCell = row.insertCell(1);
      itemCell.innerHTML = info;
      quantityCell.innerHTML = quantity;
    }
    //calls the print function
    return <a href="http://localhost:3000/Details"></a>;
  };

  render() {
    console.log("rendered");
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar
          totalCounters={this.state.counters.filter((c) => c.value > 0).length}
        />

        <main className="container">
          <Counters
            counters={this.state.counters}
            onReset={this.handleReset}
            onCreate={this.handleCreate}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
            onDecrement={this.handleDecrement}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
            onInfo={this.handleInfo}
          />
        </main>

        <div>
          <table bordered id="myList">
            <tr>
              <th>Items</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <style>
          {`
          th{
            border: 2px solid black;
            padding: 2px;
            min-width: 100px;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-style: bold;
          }
          
          td{
            border: 2px solid black;
            padding: 2px;
            min-width: 100px;
            font-size: 18px;
          }

        
          `}
        </style>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this is what my app looks like
but I want the table to be on a Details page
any help is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Router` is not a method but rather a component which wraps the application. Inside of `Router`, the `Switch` component wraps several instances of `Route`, which in turn wrap the components which are to be rendered when that route is hit. Finally the `Link` component is used to build links to various `Route` instances. All together it looks something like this:

```
import { 
    BrowserRouter as Router, 
    Switch, 
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
    <Switch>

        <Route exact path="/">
            <div>

                ...insert home page here...

                <Link to="/details">Click here to go to details page!</Link>

            </div>
        </Route>

        <Route path="/details">
            ...details page/component here...
        </Route>

    </Switch>
</Router>
```

See the [React Router Tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for more information.

Comment: is It possible to put it into the return of a function or will that not work?

Comment: Ok, i have added that and i do have a link and it does go to my http://localhost:3000/Details ..... but It keeps all the same components of the same page although i have nothing in my Details.js. does anyone have any idea why

Comment: Yes, that should be returned by the render function. If there is any content within the switch but outside the `Route`s, that will be rendered on both pages. If that isn't the issue try pass the prop `exact` to the `/` route. I've edited the example above to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks so much that worked. It was much more complicated than I thought tbh, before learning react i did all my projects in vanilla JavaScript and it was much easier to change pages